# Upgrade to magento version and not to latest version

Tags: magento, upgrade, magento-1.5, magento-1.6

I would like to upgrade Magento 1.5 to 1.6 and NOT to the latest (1.7) version.

I think I need to change something in this line, but I don't know what:

```
./mage install http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community Mage_All_Latest --force
```

I use this:

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 777 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
rm -rf var/cache/* var/session/*
chmod 550 ./mage
./mage mage-setup .
./mage config-set preferred_state stable
./mage list-installed
./mage list-upgrades
./mage install http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community Mage_All_Latest --force
php shell/indexer.php reindexall
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

Comment: and what is your question then ?

Comment: the example updates to the latest version, but I want to update to a version that is newer, but a previous one to the latest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have experience using Subversion? If you do, take a look at http://www.magentocommerce.com/svn.

**Make sure you backup your files AND database first (just in case). This may take a couple of tries to get right.**

What you want to do is checkout the 1.6 branch into your Magento folder:

```
svn checkout http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.6 /var/www/magento
```

The above assumes your Magento folder is /var/www/magento, otherwise replace the path with what makes sense for your environment.

---

Once you've got subversion working, it is easy to view changesets between versions with the `svn diff` command. But, if you're worried about changes in this upgrade, you can checkout the 1.6 version to a temporary folder, and view all the changes with a tool like diff:

```
svn checkout http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.6 /tmp/magento-1.6
diff -Naurw /var/www/magento /tmp/magento-1.6 | vim -
```

That will load the diff output into vim, where you can have nice syntax highlighting to make your eyes bleed less! You should be prepared for this to take a while, especially when going between major versions like 1.5 and 1.6.

Comment: Great! SVN is not a problem, but if I got it right, I should overwrite the updated files from my previous version? What will happen with the database? Will it automaticly update?

Comment: Yes, but you may have to clear the cache manually. Magento has builtin version detection and will run the database upgrade scripts that it finds for its modules. But, it is a good idea to backup your database first. In my experience, the database isn't always a seemless upgrade and i have had to manually fix some updates that failed.

Comment: Ah, thanks. That's exacly why I'm doing this. I've got a multishop running with a lot of modules, 1.5 to 1.7 isn't working at all and I can't find the problem... So that's why I would like to try it this way.